# Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.10

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

When running the command `sudo do-release upgrade` I'm facing the following errors:

```
Checking package manager
Can not upgrade 
An upgrade from 'cosmic' to 'eoan' is not supported with this tool.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 18.10 no longer supported you can upgrade manually to 19.04

```
mkdir /tmp/upgrade
cd /tmp/upgrade
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/disco.tar.gz
tar -xvf disco.tar.gz
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
/etc/apt/sources.list change all links prefix to -> http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/
sudo python3 dist-upgrade.py
```

Then upgrade to 19.10

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i -e 's|cosmic|eoan|g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the whole process of upgrading from 18.10 to 20.04LTS. Key steps are first upgrading from 18.10(cosmic) to 19.04(disco), then 19.10(eoan), finally 20.04LTS(focal).

1. **Upgrade from 18.10 to 19.04**. First, we have to manually download disco updates:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/upgrade
   cd /tmp/upgrade
   wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/disco.tar.gz
   tar -xf disco.tar.gz
   ```

   Now, modify ***/etc/apt/sources.list***(Tip: you'd better save the original sources.list as a backup). This file in Ubuntu 18.10 is like this:

   [image: sources.list of cosmic]

   However, "*archive.ubuntu.com*" has been dead, so we have to replace these links by "*old-releases.ubuntu.com*", then run ***dist-upgrade.py*** in current directory, which is extracted from ***disco.tar.gz***:

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/archive.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo sed -i 's/cosmic/disco/g' /etc/apt/sources.list  # some answers may forget this
   sudo python3 dist-upgrade.py
   ```

   Note that if you forget to replace "cosmic" with "disco", when running this script, it may throw this dialogue box:

   [image: No valid mirror found]

   Don't worry, choose "Yes", just like it said, it will update all "cosmic" to "disco" entries.

   When this script succeeds, reboot your system and now you have Ubuntu 19.04(disco). Your ***/etc/apt/sources.list*** should be like this:

   [image: sources.list of disco]
2. **Upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10**. Again, replace "disco" to "eoan" in ***/etc/apt/sources.list***. Now you can run apt for updating:

   ```
   sudo sed -i 's/cosmic/eoan/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

   If everything goes well, reboot your system and you got 19.10(eoan)! If you just want 19.10, feel free to skip step 3, it's for users who want 20.04 LTS.
3. **Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 LTS**. This is quite easy, just use Ubuntu Software Updater, it will do everything for you. It took me about 2-3 hours to download and install all updates.